# Simple clock sync to avoid time drift.

Tags: mining, solo-mining

What is a simple utility or command line function I can add to a batch file or run independently to automatically update the computer's clock with a NIST time server?   Ideally I'd love a utility or agent which syncs it every hour.

I've tried numerous times with Windows 10 registry options to no avail.   I've also replaced the motherboard battery.  I can 'unsync' and then 'sync' again using the Microsoft time settings interface, but it's inconvenient.

I've had clock drift while mining in the past and would love to not have to worry about this issue going forward.

Comment: Hi there. This would be better asked on one of the other Stack Exchange boards (Stack Overflow?). It's a little off-topic for the Ethereum board, so will likely get flagged as such.

Comment: I feel it relates directly to Ethereum mining and blockchain synchronization.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks I agree another SE board is more appropriate ("my disk is full; how do I move my movies off my disk so that I can fit the blockchain for mining" would similarly go there). I think the Super User Stack Exchange is the perfect place for this question: "Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users" Many questions pertaining to computer/OS configuration and tools.

Answer (score 1):

For MacOS, the following should work to sync the computer's clock with a time server (though you seem to be on Windows):

```
%> sudo sntp -s <time_server_hostname>
```

The `sudo` is needed to execute the command with root permission.

MacOS can also be set to automatically sync with a time server via **System Preferences** -> **Date & Time** settings.

On Windows, there should be something in **Control Panel** to specify a time server to automatically sync with.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the Google NTP Servers https://developers.google.com/time/ . The other public ones can be overloaded

Right-click your clock and choose Adjust date/time
Click on the Internet Time tab and then the Change Settings button
Replace the default time server with time1.google.com
Click Update Now
Do this and you should receive a confirmation that your time was successfully synchronized with the NTP server. Going forward Windows will now synchronize there once per week.